# Is there a way to skip generating a class using JAXB XML to Java?

Tags: java, jaxb, code-generation

I have a schema that I'm trying to use (unmodified) to create Java classes / enums with XJC. However for a couple of the implemented classes, I have a different implementation.

So I'm using the normal JAXB `<baseType name="..."/>` property to map to my existing implementation. The mapping works well (or at least, it compiles and the unit tests pass).

However I'm still getting generated classes that I'd prefer not to have (for reasons of jar size, plus aesthetics) if possible.

Is there a way to have XJC not generate specific classes using an external binding file? Or using some configuration of the maven plugin?

If it makes a difference, this is with Java 17 and Jakarta's JAXB 4.

Comment: That depends, do you actually want your code to work? If so, then you will need the generated classes to use JAXB. There are alternatives to JAXB. They are usually painful to implement. A [SAX parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) for example. I think it's also possible to use protocol buffers for "cheap" JSON parsing.

Comment: My alternative implementation works fine - it has hand-written JAXB annotations. I just don't want the unused classes in my `.generated` code package.

Answer (score 1):

We use XJC to generate java classes from xsd's and dtd's but found that the provided maven plugin didn't suit our needs (I can't remember the exact details of why). As a workaround we invoke `com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver` using the [maven-antrun-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) and [antcontrib](https://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/). You might find something useful in the pom.xml

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-model</id>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>
                    <delete dir="${project.basedir}/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myproject/model" />
                    <for param="dtd">
                        <path>
                            <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/schema/path1">
                                <include name="Type1.dtd" />
                                <include name="Type2.dtd" />
                                <include name="Type3.dtd" />
                            </fileset>
                        </path>
                        <sequential>
                            <local name="fileName"/>
                            <basename property="fileName" file="@{dtd}" suffix=".dtd"/>
                            <java classname="com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver" fork="true">
                                <sysproperty key="enableExternalEntityProcessing" value="true"/>
                                <arg value="-p" />
                                <arg value="com.mycompany.myproject.model.path1.${fileName}" />
                                <arg value="-d" />
                                <arg value="${project.basedir}/src/main/java" />
                                <arg value="-dtd" />
                                <arg value="-XautoNameResolution" />
                                <arg value="@{dtd}" />
                                <classpath>
                                    <path refid="maven.plugin.classpath" />
                                </classpath>
                            </java>
                        </sequential>
                    </for>
                    <for param="xsd">
                        <path>
                            <fileset includes="*.xsd" dir="${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/schema/path2" />
                        </path>
                        <sequential>
                            <java classname="com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver" fork="true">
                                <sysproperty key="enableExternalEntityProcessing" value="true"/>
                                <arg value="-p" />
                                <arg value="com.mycompany.myproject.model.path2" />
                                <arg value="-d" />
                                <arg value="${project.basedir}/src/main/java" />
                                <arg value="-XautoNameResolution" />
                                <arg value="@{xsd}" />
                                <classpath>
                                    <path refid="maven.plugin.classpath" />
                                </classpath>
                            </java>
                        </sequential>
                    </for>
                    <replaceregexp match="\Q// Generated on:\E.*" replace="//" byline="true">
                        <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myproject/model" />
                    </replaceregexp>
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ant-contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-contrib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0b3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ant</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.istack</groupId>
            <artifactId>istack-commons-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks - I guess I could just delete the file by name (in the same way you `replaceregexp`). Will consider that.

Comment: Are you talking about deleting the generated java files? Personally I'd try to exclude / delete the xsd files so you don't waste time generating files you don't need

Comment: Its all in one XSD, which I'm trying to use unmodified.

Comment: Ah, perhaps you need to transform the xml first to remove the entries you don't want. Then run xjc over the trimmed xml